# Sqlite Join error

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I am trying to connect 2 tables to extract values from them, but I get an error that does not do.

CODE:

```
Class Product:

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (ID INTEGER, NOMBRE TEXT, PRECIO REAL, CANTIDAD INTEGER, ESTADO CHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY(ID))");
    }
```

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

if (newVersion > oldVersion) {

```
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PRODUCT");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (ID INTEGER, NOMBRE TEXT, PRECIO REAL, CANTIDAD INTEGER, ESTADO CHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY(ID))");
```

LINE OF ERROR:

```
SQLiteDatabase bd2 = admin.getWritableDatabase();

fbd2 = bd2.rawQuery("SELECT ID, CANTIDAD, MONTO, PRECIO, NOMBRE FROM PRODUCT P INNER JOIN CUERPO C ON PRODUCT.ID = CUERPO.ID_PRODUCT", null);
```

ERROR:

```
no such table: PRODUCT
```

Comment: The table is created as Product. You do the select with PRODUCTO

Comment: I want to know if the join is fine, edited  post

Comment: Are you sure that the onCreate is being called?  You may need to recreate the database

Comment: Edited post, now you can see onUpgrade Method

Comment: In your onUpgrade you are creating table Producto, but onCreate you are creating PRODUCT.  Tienes que escoger un idioma :)

Comment: I can do Selects from Table Product.

Comment: Can you put the complete error? Also have you looked at SugarORM? Very easy to use for database stuff like this.

Comment: Edited Post, table called PRODUCTO, but i translate because here its english people.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond that's the error: no such table: Product

Comment: It looks like you may have a version issue.  Try increasing the database version number so that it forces it to recreate.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond same error when increase version.

Comment: Use the data analysis tools in Android studio to take a look at the actual database and you can see what is there and what isn't.  Beyond that I can't really help much

Comment: Thank you! I will search about see tables in android studio